# Set PloneFormGen to send mail to a group of users

Tags: plone, plone-4.x, ploneformgen

I have a form created with PloneFormGen and a group of users in my plone website. How to configure Mailer Adapter Recipient Expression (in myform/mailer/edit - Overrides) to send mail to this group of users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unluckily I don't think you can use `plone.api` methods here as you are in the restricted python

Try something like:

```
python:[user.getProperty('email') for user in object.portal_groups.getGroupById('YOURGROUPID').getGroupMembers()]
```

Comment: What a pretty neat oneliner.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://plone.org/products/collective.contentrules.mailtogroup and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.groupmail though they may not be directly usable from PFG. You might have to create something intermediate that is callable from a PFG form that uses these.

I've had lots of success emailing groups of users with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.easytemplate - it lets you create content rules (and pages and portlets) that contain expressions that can do almost anything.

Comment: BTW: c.c.mailtogroup's newest vs. 1.5 broke the usage of var-substitues, latest working vs. is 1.3.1, the responsible contributors haven't replied, yet to: https://github.com/collective/collective.contentrules.mailtogroup/issues/4 Thanks for pointing out the other possibilities!